# how to return both controller variables and view html contents as ajax json response

Tags: php, ajax, json, cakephp

I am using CakePHP and using MVC standards.

I am sending a request using ajax and need a response in the same manner as tweeter response, see tweeter sample response below.

Like tweeter sends:

```
{
"user_id":"155dsfds95",
"html":" \u003Cdiv class=\"module profile-card component profile-header\" data-component-term=\"profile_follow_card\" \u003E\n ",
"screen_name":"abc"
}
```

I need to send `user_id` and `screen_name` from controller and `html` content from view.

my response data is as follow:

```
$response['user_id'] = $id;
$response['screen_name'] = 'some_name';
```

As of now I can send `user_id` and `screen_name` as `json_encode($response)`

But how do I send view content also in `data` index with the response?

**UPDATES**

I do not want to make html content in controller, rather it should come from view.

Comment: Are you asking how you get a rendered view within a controller?

Comment: Hello jeremyharris, I do not want to make html content in controller due to MVC contraints. How to achieve this like tweeter.

Comment: Have you looked at JSON Views? http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html - assuming you are in CakePHP 2

Comment: Yes david, i have looked at JSON Views, but in json/XML views also, we can only manipulate data coming from controller. What i need is send view content in one json key along with another json key created at controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily render the current view from your controller and return a JSON response with it.

Working example:

```
public function index() {
    $response = $this->render();
    $data = array(
        'json_key_1' => 'value1',
        'json_key_2' => 123,
        'action_html' => $response->body()
    );
    $options = array(
        'type' => 'json',
        'body' => json_encode($data)
    );
    return new CakeResponse($options);
}
```

Comment: Sorry for responding so late, this answer didn't come to my notice and today i accidently seen the answer, when i once again needed for this kind of functionality. +1 and accepting this answer. thanks